# C#, авторизация на WordPress

Tags: c#, wordpress

Как можно реализовать авторизацию на WordPress через c# (для добавления, редактирования, удаления постов). WordPress 4.9. Смотрел в сторону rpc-xml.net, но, изучив их сайт, пришел к выводу, что проект остановился и не развивается примерно с 2010 года. Это ещё WordPress 3.0. Боюсь потратить время. Потом набрёл, что у вп теперь появились rest api, но как ими пользоваться, нигде вразумительного руководства не нашел. В основном одни обзоры, из которых следует, что вроде как на нем можно все. Вот только как, не понятно. Ну и вариант с webclient или httpclient, но какие формировать запросы в голову не идёт. Как это сделать проще и безболезненней?

Comment: Может это подойдет [WordPressSharp](http://abrudtkuhl.github.io/WordPressSharp/)

Comment: Посмотрите по [аналогии](https://github.com/PetersSharp/DokuWikiConnector) с этим, xml-rpc там должно работать, раньше было по крайней мере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [официальная документация](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) по REST API. Есть примеры на c#

[Аутентификация](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-basic-authentication--cms-24762)

[Добавление и удаление постов](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-creating-updating-and-deleting-data--cms-24883)

[Есть целая библиотека на C#](https://github.com/wp-net/WordPressPCL)

Мне кажется, этого вполне достаточно, чтобы написать свой код.